# insert rel attribute with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, rel

I have this function :

```
 if (location.locationUrl != '') {
content += "<a class='viewLocationPage btn corePrettyStyle'  " +   
(mapObject.options.openinnew == false ? "" : "target='_blank'") +  
" href='" + location.locationUrl + "' >View location detail</a>";
        }
```

and I've added the **rel** attribute like this:

```
if (location.locationUrl != '') {
            content += "<a class='viewLocationPage btn corePrettyStyle'  " + 
            (mapObject.options.openinnew == false ? "" : "target='_blank'") +
            "rel='prettyPhoto[iframes]'" + " href='" + location.locationUrl + "' >View location detail</a>";
        }
```

but is not working, it doesn't add any rel attribute into the markup. Any suggestions on how can I make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, it'd be easier to create the element with the jQuery constructor:

```
if (location.locationUrl != '') {
    $('<a>', {
        'class': 'viewLocationPage btn corePrettyStyle',
        target: mapObject.options.openinnew ? '_blank' : '',
        rel: 'prettyPhoto[iframes]',
        href: location.locationUrl,
        text: 'View location detail'
    }).appendTo('#selector');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm  interested also in the javascript version because the rest of the code is mainly written in javascript

Comment: @Alecs: Then use `document.createElement`.

Comment: I've tried it and is not working, probably because of .appendTo so is it possible to insert the rel in the code that I've posted?

Comment: @Alecs: The way you're doing it isn't going to work very well.

Comment: I've set the appendTo to the container div

Comment: It doesn't append it to the container element, when I check I don't see anything in the markup.

Comment: @Alecs: The code works, so the problem is elsewhere. Do you do something like `container.innerHTML = content` after this?